# Is there a way to use Wagtail Snippets to display existing Django Models?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

With Wagtail CMS, what is the best way to mimic the "Plugin" functionality of Django CMS?

In Django CMS I am able to write a [custom plugin](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html) that can display a template and any related information to that model. Content Managers can then add that plugin to a placeholder anywhere on the site.

With Wagtail, the closest thing I can find is the [Snippet](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/snippets.html), but each time you use the Snippet you have to include it specifically in the Page model.

Take these two models for example:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
   species = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

For the content manager to be able to access these I'd need to register them as snippets, and then list each model in that page's model like so:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        SnippetChooserPanel('pet'),
        SnippetChooserPanel('book'),
    ]
```

Is there a better way to do this with Wagtail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this kind of solution without defining models you could look at the StreamField approach.

You could define a custom StreamField block type that models `pets` or `books`. Make this available on the pages that need this, you still have to be explicit about which pages can use this StreamField though.

You can then define a custom template that renders these items, available in the documentation:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer. Confirms my assumption that the snippets have to be explicitly declared. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this kind of solution with a generic defined template you could define a method on both the `Book` and `Pets` classes.

Something like:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    template = 'path/to/template.html'

    get_as_html(self):
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(self.template, {'self': self}))
```

You would need to create the template file that handles the Book instance. This means that you can easily call `{{ Book.get_has_html }}` within any templates that use the Book snippet.